# Android change google maps zoom buttons style

Tags: android, google-maps, debugging

Question is about how to get `resources` of `google map`, to change `background` these buttons. 
So, i've found solution via debugger:

```
View mapView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);   

// Get the button view 
View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(1).getParent()).findViewById(2);
```

But i cant understand how to get `ID's` views i need with debugger

Answer (score 0):

use findViewById(*hardcode*) no safely.

Better disable native control(setZoomControlsEnabled(false)) and attach yours(you will have full access eg animation, color, styles, characters, drawable etc).

Comment: can you include the source, in where you get this information.

Comment: is there any documentation in where you get this information?

Comment: no. i haven't documentation. Also i didn't found any doc which guarantee unchanged direct ID. if on next build p-services ID will be changed application will work incorrectly.